# NSSocketPort connection in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to make a socket connection with this code

```
//Server code
- (void)startServer{
    sockPort = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initWithTCPPort:9786];
    NSConnection *theConnection;
    theConnection = [[NSConnection alloc] initWithReceivePort:sockPort sendPort:nil];
    theConnection=[[NSConnection alloc] init];
    [theConnection setRootObject:self];
    [theConnection registerName:@"Server Connection"];
}

//Client Code
-(void)startClient{
     NSConnection *conn=[NSConnection connectionWithReceivePort:nil sendPort:sockPort];
     NSLog(@"Socket descriptor=%d",[sockPort socket]);
}
```

console

```
Socket descriptor=-1
```

why socket descriptor is showing -1?

Answer (score 1):

The code posted doesn't particular make sense - but if we assume the client side of the code was a little more conventional and looked like:

```
- (void)startClient
{
    NSSocketPort *sockPort = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initRemoteWithTCPPort: 1234
                                                                    host: @"hostname"];
    NSConnection  *connection = [NSConnection  connectionWithReceivePort: nil 
                                                                sendPort: sockPort];
    ....
```

The socket on sockPort here should be -1, as it doesn't represent a socket in that process, rather a destination a such socket should be connected to.

Of more interest are receivePort and sendPort properties on the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double alloc. The second should be removed.